# bootstrap 3 section overlap below section

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded the template at http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/ and added some image on the intro section but the image I need is a bit large and overlap the section below it when view under smaller screen like when I minimized the width of the browser. Also, the right content overlap the left content (image) when minimize browser. Below are the code:

```
    <section id="intro" class="intro-section" style="background:#ffffff">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="text-align:right;border:0px solid #ccc">
                <div style="position:relative;top: 0">

                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="asset/img/samsung_galaxy_tab_a_white_front_fit.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0"/>

                    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 61px; left: 29px;width: 392px; height: 520px;">
                        <!-- Slides Container -->
                        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;overflow: hidden;width: 392px; height: 520px;">                      
                            <div><img u="image" src="asset/img/guestarrive_visitor_completion.png" style="position: absolute"/></div>
                            <div><img u="image" src="asset/img/guestarrive_show_visitor_agreement.png" style="position: absolute"/></div>
                            <div><img u="image" src="asset/img/guesarrive_default_screen.png" style="position: absolute"/></div>
                            <div><img u="image" src="asset/img/guestarrive_quick_reg.png" style="position: absolute"/></div>                                                                                                                                
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                </div>                                      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="border:0px solid #ccc">
                <span style="font-size:60px;">
                    Recycle your visitor log book today and impress every guest with GuestArrive :D
                </span>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: use `media query` for smaller screen styling.

Comment: I suggest you to add these `col-sm-6 col-xs-12` also in  this `<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="border:0px solid #ccc">`

Comment: NOTE:- Only using bootstrap doesn't make site responsive you have to make it responsive by defining styles for the content that how to display in mobile,tablet and desktop.